# styling one list item

Tags: css

I have four li's and I want to style the 4th li not to have the background image. How do I accomplish this without having to insert a spam tag?

```
#get-help ul.help-menu li {
color: #656565;
background:url("/ContentTemplates/assets/images/backgrounds/nav-brdr.png")      
no-repeat scroll 50% 100% transparent;
width: 226px;
text-indent: 10px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To style the **4th** list item, you can use the `nth-child` selector, though it is not supported in Internet Explorer.

```
#get-help ul.help-menu li:nth-child(4) {
  background: none;
}
```

If you mean the last item (independent of how many list items there are), use `:last-child` instead of `:nth-child(4)`.

If you need full support, you might want to try Javascript or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). (Search at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you are not sure how.)

The simplest solution is to add a class to the 4th item manually, or as you generate the HTML if it comes from a script. There is nothing really wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#navlist li:last-child { background:none; }
```

Very similar to this request over at SO: [Stack Overflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004075/how-to-remove-ul-unordered-lists-last-li-list-items-border-using-css-withou)

Comment: Just keep in mind this will not work in any version of IE currently available.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That only styles the last item, not the 4th.